# CSS Padding moves more than 1 pixel on <h1> tag

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why `padding-top: 0px` to `padding-top: 1px;` moves the `<h1>` element more than 1 pixel. Increasing it further, to for instance 2 pixels, will have the expected result.

CSS

```
.pageholder {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    //padding-top: 1px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="pageholder">
            <h1>Add item link</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

...aaand finally, a jsfiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xbAqC/

(*remove the // to see the difference*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Padding on the inner div prevents [margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).  The default top margin of the `<h1>` is collapsing with the `<body>`'s margin when the padding is not there.  The padding prevents this.

You can see the difference by removing the `<body>`'s margin: http://jsfiddle.net/xbAqC/2/

Answer (score 0):

H1 tags have their own margin and padding. Set your h1's padding and margin to 0 and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You set a padding-top AND a padding. Both can't co-exist. There are 2 ways to solve it. One is to just remove the padding and add a different padding to each side, and the second (better) one is to add a padding which exists for every side together but with different values:

```
padding: 16px 15px 15px 15px;
```

In the example above, the first number is the top, second is right, third bottom and fourth left. The numbers start from the top and go clockwise.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbAqC/1/)

Comment: good answer, but OP does want a 1 px padding on the top and not 16 px

Answer (score -1):

try this: [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbAqC/3/)

```
.pageholder h1 {
    padding:15px ;
    padding-top: 1px;
    //padding-top: 1px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: had you added some explanation it would have been clear that you had changed something, and I would not have embarrassed myself like that. I apologize for not seeing the difference in your code from everyone else's.